# ImageMagick on Azure Functions cannot load native library

Tags: azure, imagemagick, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools, magicknet

I'm trying to use Magick.NET library to do image processing on Azure Functions.

I have tried the same code in a Console App (.NET Core 3.1) which works without any issues. However when running the same code in an Azure Functions Project, I get the following error.

**Code:**

`var image = new MagickImage(File.ReadAllBytes(@"<My Image Path>"));`

**Exception:**

`System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'NativeMagickSettings' threw an exception.'`

**StackTrace:**

```
at ImageMagick.MagickSettings.NativeMagickSettings..ctor()
at ImageMagick.MagickSettings..ctor()
at ImageMagick.MagickImage..ctor()
at ImageMagick.MagickImage..ctor(Byte[] data)
at FunctionApp2.Function1.Run(TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log) <-- My Code
```

**Inner Exception:**

`Unable to load DLL 'Magick.Native-Q8-x64.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)`

**Inner Exception StackTrace**

```
at ImageMagick.Environment.NativeMethods.X64.Environment_Initialize()
at ImageMagick.Environment.NativeEnvironment.Initialize()
at ImageMagick.Environment.Initialize()
at ImageMagick.MagickSettings.NativeMagickSettings..cctor()
```

I believe this is due to the way Azure Functions package is organized and the path Magick.NET is looking for its native binary to load. I can confirm that the native binary is written at `\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\runtimes\<platform>\native` when the Function app is built.

I have traced the apps using ProcessMonitor for each app and can see Function app looks in the wrong location.

It looks in

> \bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\ **bin\** runtimes\[platform]\native

instead of

> \bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\runtimes\[platform]\native

(Below traces are filtered to only show `path contains Magick.Native` and process name filtered to the Console app exe and func.exe)

[Console App Trace](https://pastebin.com/i94vDB41)
[image: Console App Trace]

[Function App Trace](https://pastebin.com/FnzAhu21)
[image: Function App Trace]

I have also tried setting `MagickAnyCPU.CacheDirectory` to `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` but it hasn't helped.

---

**UPDATE:**

After building, if I copy `\netcoreapp3.1\runtimes` folder to `\bin` this fixes the problem, but I current don't want to rely on that trick if there's a proper workaround.

**UPDATE 2:**

This issue appears to happen only when using
`<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>`
and `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` version `3.0.x`

It does not appear when using older versions. I have successfully used
`<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>`
and `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` version `1.0.x`
without this issue.

---

So, is there a workaround to get ImageMagick to load native lib from the right place?

---

**Potential Workaround** is to get msbuild to copy the `runtimes` folder after the build completes.

Add following to csproj

```
  <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="xcopy /Y /E $(OutDir)runtimes\ $(OutDir)bin\runtimes\" />
  </Target>
```

or right click project > properties > Build Events and paste the above command to `post build event command line`

This will copy all of the `runtimes` binaries, not just the one we want, increasing the size of final build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

This may be a bug in `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` version `3.0.8`.
These issues in the github repo are tracking this.

1. [Version 3.0.8 places the runtimes folder incorrectly](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/437)
2. [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform with Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 3.0.8](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/436)

---

This seems to only happen when using `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` version `3.0.8` which seems to have only just appeared in nuget on Friday. I will instead downgrade to `3.0.7`.

Alternatively if you don't want to downgrade,

> [You could use `MagickNET.SetNativeLibraryDirectory` as a work around](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/discussions/689#discussioncomment-33906)